# SharePoint Online server resource quotas

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hope you're well;

at this current time I have 1000 server resource quotas set on one site collection which has 39 subsites.

What will happen if i change resourcer quotas higher?

kind regards,
Anees

Answer (score 3):

Resource quotas were designed for Sandbox solutions. The quota system no longer does anything as Sandbox solutions are no longer allowed (or at least, code-based are no longer allowed).

You can ignore the quota number as it does not do anything.

Comment: is there an url flor this information

Comment: The removal is noted at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online/ and a bit more info at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Server-Resource-Quota/td-p/203255.